# Method for Combining Multiple Word Documents into One?

Tags: mac, ms-office

Are there any methods for combining multiple Word documents into one big document in Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert > File. You have to do it one at a time, but it appears to work.

Comment: In 2020, just drag&drop files to the Word window.

Answer (score 2):

Use Automator. It has a "Combine Word Documents" option as one of its premade Document Library items.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word 2011 for Mac, no, there is no method for combining MULTIPLE files into one big document at the same time. You can, however, combine the files one at a time. Here's what you do: Click INSERT / FILE, and follow the prompts to insert one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 15.40 (Office 2016 Mac), I've successfully merged multiple files into one with this process:

1. Open a new document and use the View menu > Master Document option.
2. Open up a Finder window to the directory containing your files
3. Click and drag files into the new document. This should copy the contents into the master document.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work anymore. Dragging documents into the Master Document view just adds the first page of each document as an object.

Answer (score 0):

The Automator approach should work, but returns an error.

I found a workaround: Nisus, another word processor for the mac, let's you simply drag in .docx files from the finder. I selected 120 files, dragged them in and it was done in three minutes.