# How can I combine multiple Word files into one?

Tags: automator, ms-office

There's an old answer to this question here: [Method for Combining Multiple Word Documents into One?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10702/method-for-combining-multiple-word-documents-into-one)

But the top rated answer is to just do it manually by inserting one at a time. I have to believe there's a more convenient solution to this in 2023 (I have 100 Word Documents containing tables that I need to merge into a single document, and can't do it manually).

Automator also doesn't seem to be an option since the "Combine Word Files" feature has been replaced with "Combine text files" which doesn't do the same thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this procedure fail in MS Word for the Mac? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/merge-word-documents

Comment: Unfortunately, no. On Mac you can only select files one at a time.

Comment: FYI, I think microsoft stopped supporting automator a couple of versions ago, which is probably why the 'combine word documents' action no longer exists (NB apple changed stuff which is what caused it). However, the 'combine text files' action comes with the computer (and dates back to 2004) so it's not a replacement for the missing word action. As an aside, always include the version, otherwise it's just a bad guessing game as to what might work.